# GreenDAO: store list of entities in other entity

Tags: android, greendao

I am playing around with GreenDAO and I think I like the way it works. I do not like to write SQL code, so this will help me avoid it ;)

But still, I think it really is very 'sql'-based thinking of how you set it up. Not sure if this is a bad thing (to know how things work), but I'd rather just say: here is my object! Store it! But I haven't found anything for this yet...

But ok, what I am doing is sort of the following: I have an object, let's say a bookshelve. I put some books on the shelve.

This would look something like:

```
class BookShelve {
    List<Book> books;

    void add(Book b) {
        books.add(b);
    }
}


BookShelve bs = new BookShelve();
Book b1 = new Book();
Book b2 = new Book();
Book b3 = new Book();
bs.add(b1);
bs.add(b2);
bs.add(b3);
```

ok, now I want to store this using GreenDAO. Do I need to use 'addToMany' for this? So:

```
Property bookDataProperty = bookData.addLongProperty("bookShelve").getProperty();
ToMany books = BookShelve.addToMany(bookData, bookDataProperty); 
books.setName("Books");
```

and then do a:

```
bs.getBooks()
```

to get them? Or is there a better way?

I think it should be done like this, but I am not fully convinced yet.

ps: there may be typo's in the code above, I just wrote it here, haven't compiled it :)

**Edit:**
This came up after I gave the 'answer' check:

so, to add books to a shelve, I need to:

```
b1.setBookShelve(bs.getId());
daoSession.insert(b1);
```

right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you don't have to know SQL, but you'll have to know basic Database knowledge and be clear to your E-R Model, which I think you already have.

If you use greenDAO and implement the relationship between **Book** and **BookShelf**, you don't need to keep the list of books in your BookShelf enity.

In your DaoGenerator.java , you simply declare the schema

```
    Entity bookShelf = schema.addEntity("BookShelf");
    bookShelf.addIdProperty();

    Entity book = schema.addEntity("Book");
    book.addIdProperty();
    book.addStringProperty("name");
    Property bookFKShelves = book.addLongProperty("bookShelf_id").notNull().getProperty();

    book.addToOne(bookShelf, bookFKShelves);
    bookShelf.addToMany(book, bookFKShelves);
```

Once your generate the code. Use them in your Android code:

```
        DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this.getActivity(),
                "BookStore", null);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        mDaoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        mDaoSession = mDaoMaster.newSession();
        BookDao mBookDao = mDaoSession.getBookDao();
        BookShelfDao mBookShelfDao = mDaoSession.getBookShelfDao();

        // Insert
        BookShelf bs = new BookShelf();
        Book b1 = new Book();   b1.setName("B1");   b1.setBookShelf(bs);
        Book b2 = new Book();   b2.setName("B2");   b2.setBookShelf(bs);
        Book b3 = new Book();   b3.setName("B3");   b3.setBookShelf(bs);

        mBookDao.insert(b1);
        mBookDao.insert(b2);
        mBookDao.insert(b3);
        mBookShelfDao.insert(bs);

        // Select
        for(BookShelf bss :mBookShelfDao.loadAll()){
            for (Book b :bss.getBookList())
                Lod.d(TAG,"Book Name: "+b.getName());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Giving 'accepted answer' to you. As in my edit, indeed, I need to set the ID of the bookshelf to the book and then I don't need a list of books. Thanks for the elaborate example. btw: OMG, I wrote 'bookshelve' instead of 'bookshelf' :x

Answer (score 2):

Basically you don't need to know sql for greendao:

You just define your entities (object-classes) and relations between them.

To your question:

There are two possibilities:

- Bookshelve can contain many books and one book can only be in one bookshelve: Your approach is correct.
- bookshelve can contain many books and one book can be in many bookshelves: You should define an emtity bookshelve2book which stores the pairs.

Comment: Thanks for you quick and clear comment! About the SQL: I found out that I need to daoSession.insert(b1) also (did not find this in documentation). Otherwise getBook() would return null. Also the QueryBuilder is clearly SQL, but in a way that you cannot make typo's. Still think this is the best thing out there (which i tried of course)

Comment: Of course you can build sql queries with greendao, but you don't have to. The most inportant queries are already included in greendao: getBooks () for example.