# How to Perform the following query using Greendao ?

Tags: android, sql, greendao

I have 2 tables A and B.

Table A contains **names** and table B contains **selected names**.

Now I would like to perform the following query on these tables using greendao, Please let me know if it is possible and if it is not are there any alternatives (maybe a raw query).

```
select * 
from A inner join B
on A.nameid = B.nameid
```

Also, Table A columns: `id, nameid, name`
and Table B columns: `id, nameid, name, rating`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this might help.
You can use the raw query as a fake join. And you get all you want in the Query object

```
Query query = ATableDao.queryBuilder().where(
new StringCondition("nameid IN " +
"(SELECT nameid FROM B_Table )").build();
```

Since "nameid" doesn't seems to be a unique identifier in your sample. I won't suggest to use Relations to solve this issue. If you are try to use [Relations](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/), you can find my previous answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215668/greendao-store-list-of-entities-in-other-entity/21230885#21230885)

Comment: You should use the TABLENAME and the Properties to avoid typos.

Comment: @AlexS You are right XD. I just copy that from the document XD

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<ATableObj> listATableObj = ATableDao.queryRawCreate(", BTable BT 
WHERE BT.nameid = T.nameid").list();
```

Comment: This is weird, this method does not exist. I am using GreenDao 1.2.0. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Try with GreenDao 1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

If you use greendao this works differntly:

Instead of your query you select rows from table a (or b) and if you need a field of b (or a) you call `getB()` (or `getA()`) to get the corresponding row of that table.

If you have rows in table a that have no match in table b and you have rows in table b that have no match in a and you onlly want to select everything that has matches uin both tables, you would have to do a raw query to filter the rows of a (or b).

Comment: can you give me an example of the raw query ?